# .htaccess redirect not working properly?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am facing a problem with this .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
    RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I try to access to www.example.org/hello/howareyou, it rewrites the URL to www.example.org/hello/howareyou?page=hello/howareyou, it's like is not reading the "page=$1".

I have tried hundreds of .htaccess combinations but none helps me.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your URL changing in browser to `http://www.example.org/hello/howareyou?page=hello/howareyou` ?

Comment: Yes, this is what we see

Comment: Is there any other code in this .htaccess? Also `/hello/howareyou/` is not a real directory right?

Comment: This is the only code we have in the .htaccess file, /hello/howareyou does exist AS folder, but it shouldn't obey to the folder route

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash to real directory paths
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Make sure to test it in a new browser or clear your browser cache.